# NGINX rewrite rules not working

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am playing with NGINX rewrite rules, but no matter what I do, things wont work.

The current link:

- `/tutorials/index.php?article=2`

How I want it

- `/tutorials/2`

My - current - NGINX  rewrite conf/rule:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404 /index.php?$args;
    rewrite ^/tutorials/([0-9]+)$ /tutorials/index.php?article=$1 last;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

My NGINX configuration file:

```
server {

        # Hide php extension: ".php"
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
        }

        # Redirect to HTTPS
        if ($scheme = http) {  return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }

        # Access rule(s)
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404 /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ ^/tutorials/([[:digit:]]+)$ {
                rewrite ^ /tutorials/index.php?article=$1 last;
        }

        # Enable: PHP FPM
        location ~ \.php$ {
                if ($request_uri ~ /tutorials/index\.php) {
                        return 302 $scheme://$host/tutorials/$arg_article;
                }

                # Allow user execution of PHP
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-alpha.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                client_max_body_size 5M;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `/(.*)` in your rule?

Comment: @sebasth I couldn't not get this it work, so I started to try random things, see if that works...

Comment: @sebasth any suggestions on how I can this to work?

Comment: Did you try `rewrite ^/tutorials/([0-9]+)$ /tutorials/index.php?article=$1 last;`?

Comment: @sebasth just did. It wasnt working. I tested it, by adding a HTML link, with `href` pointing to: `/tutorials/2`. When I press it, I get a 404...

Comment: @blade19899, I think you should also confirm what actually works — is going to `/tutorials/index.php?article=2` directly actually works?  Because if not, then none of our advice would matter; and, otherwise, the above suggestion has little reason of not working.

Comment: Going to `/tutorials/index.php?article=2` works. Going to `/tutorials/2` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

NGINX has a notion of external vs. internal redirects.

It sounds like you basically want to create a redirect loop, but then break said loop through discrimination based on whether the request is received externally vs. internally.

It sounds like your spec for external URL is: `/tutorials/([[:digit:]]+)`.

It sounds like your spec for internal URL is: `/tutorials/index.php?article=$1`.

If so, then you probably want the following:

```
location ~ ^/tutorials/([[:digit:]]+)$ {
    rewrite ^ /tutorials/index.php?article=$1 last;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    if ($request_uri ~ /tutorials/index\.php) {
        return 302 $scheme://$host/tutorials/$arg_article;
    }
    fastcgi_…
}
```

Comment: This kinda worked. The urls changes from `/index.php?article=2` to `/tutorials/2`, but I get a `404`. Not the actual page...

Comment: @blade19899, there is absolutely no way it wouldn't work for you — you reported above that `/tutorials/index.php?article=2` was working properly; absent intentional configuration to the contrary, it is impossible for one to work, and for the other to fail at the very same time (and if it really still doesn't work, then you'll have to provide the complete config where the problem is seen)

Comment: I added the conf file in my Q. I edited with just the important parts to to this question.

Comment: Duh!  Your `.php` addition is totally wrong, and obviously interferes with the rest of the config.  Moreover, the problem should have been obvious if you would have looked at the `error_log` — it should have had the obvious "/tutorials/1.php" not found / does not exist message.  If you still need the directive, you'd probably have to move it to within `location /`.

Comment: I think I got it working. Only thing now, is that I need it to also catch `word-12-33-longerword`. Not just `:digit:`. I tried `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`. But after that I get 404. What is the proper regex for this?

Comment: @blade19899 that was never mentioned or implied in the question; it seems like I've answered your question in full now, you still haven't +1'ed or accepted it, yet still feel the need to ask for additional help?  The proper syntax would be `([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)`, or `([^/]+)` for a more inclusive regex.

Comment: My apologies I thought I already upvoted. I'll try out the regex.

Comment: I tried them out: The first regex, it just gives out 404, and the second one gives me a '500 Internal Server Error' message. I am developing a personal project, in testing I used the /tutorials/2, but in production the '/tutorials/some-tutorial-test' should be used, I completely forgot about this. Again, my apologies on this.

Comment: second one should be also exclude dot to not match `.php`, `([^/.]+)`, for the first one, it sounds like you're missing the `-` before `a` that I added to the one you had.